# Property in Entity partial class

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an entity/table that uses sqlgeography.

Since EF 4.X doesn't support spatial types I'm instead sending the bytes of the field back and forth.

I have stored procs on the database side that handles the converstion and properties on the code side to do that job.

To add the properties in the code I used a partial class.

One of those properties is for the SqlGeography which simply wraps around the byte[] property to handle getting and setting.

This property is hidden from EF using the NotMappedAttribute.

The other is the property exposing the byte[] itself and is decorated with the EdmScalarPropertyAttribute and DataMemberAttribute.

I then go to the EF model designer (*.edmx) to point the entity model at the Insert/Update/Delete stored procs.

It finds the stored procs alright and realises that they (when appropriate) take a VARBINARY parameter.

It also has a drop down allowing you to select a property on the entity class which maps to that parameter.

However this drop down doesn't list either of my properties. I don't care about the SqlGeography property since that is meant to be hidden from EF, however it is vital for me to be able to point it at the byte[] property, as that is where the data comes from.

I would very much like to avoid database triggers or wrapper classes and addiitonal fields to fudge this in to working.

I tried manually editing the .edmx file to include the byte[] property, but then it just complains it's unmapped.

Can anyone give me some insight in to how to get this to work? Or an alternative method of achiving the end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we created a computed column for each table that exposes the spatial data as bytes.

We then use stored procs for inserting and updating the spatial data.

Answer (score 1):

We could use a view to create the binary field for us, but this then involves manually creating a lot of the xml for the relationships within the data.

This pretty much voids the point of using EF which is to make life simple and easy.

For this project We'll just add a binary field to the table then have sprocs to handle the converstion on the server and a property in a partial entity class for exposing the geography type in the model.

Next project I doubt we'll be using EF. Dapper is so much more painless, even if theres a touch more code writing involved.

Here's the links for using views if anyone thinks it would be applicable to them:

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/yes-you-can-read-and-probably-write-spatial-data-with-entity-framework/

http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/